# How to insert a new ListItem Record into Entity table using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to inserd new record into my entity Table.

While binding the records to Dropdownlist, we add one new ListItem like "- Select One -".

If it is using ADO.NET Datasets, it is much simpler as below.
But now i am using Entity Model.

Ex using ADO.NET:

```
ListItemCollection var_NewLists = new ListItemCollection();
        ListItem dummyItem = new ListItem();
        dummyItem.Value = "";
        dummyItem.Text = "- Select One -";
        var_NewLists.Add(dummyItem);
        foreach (DataRow theRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Value = theRow[P_Id].ToString();
            newItem.Text = theRow[Name].ToString();
            var_NewLists.Add(newItem);
        }
```

Now i want to do the same using Entity Model and i want to insert new record into this list before i bind it to the Dropdown.

Here is my Product table from Entity.

```
var product =
          (from p in miEntity.Product
           where p.Pipeline == false
           orderby p.Name
           select new
           {
               P_Id = p.P_Id,
               P_Name = p.Name
           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList(Model.Products, "ID", "Name"), "Select one") %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504970.aspx

`optionLabel` - Type: `System.String` - **The text for a default empty item. This parameter can be null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).**